# Projet_Flask - Arguments error

Tags: python, flask

I'm currently doing a project on Flask. One of my my page is the login page. I'm habing an error on this page

> TypeError: accueil_template() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were
>   given

Here is my app.py code :

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['POST'])
def do_admin_login():

    if request.form['password'] == 'password' and request.form['username'] `== 'admin'`:

        session['logged_in'] = True
        return accueil_template
    else:
        flash('wrong password!')
    return accueil_template()
```

And my HTML code is the following one :

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block titre %}
    Acceuil
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% if session['logged_in'] %}
    <p>You're logged in already!</p>
    {% else %}
    <form action="/login/" method="POST">
    <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="{{
        request.form.username }}">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="{{
        request.form.password }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

I don't understand What happen ? Why I have this error ?

Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with last line, you are calling a function `return accueil_template()`, remove the call (see `if` block return statement)